# Python Program will not create output file

Tags: python, file, input, output

So I am writing a program to read a file, take some input and then output the result to a file but no matter what I do I cannot seem to get the output file to actually appear. Any help will be appreciated. Here's my code

```
import os.path
endofprogram = False

try:
    filename1 = input("Enter the name of input file: ")
    infile = open(filename1, 'r')
    filename2 = input("Enter the name of output file: ")
    if os.path.isfile(filename2) == True:
        filename2 = input("File Exists! Enter new name for output file: ")
        infile = open(filename1, 'r')
        ofile = open(filename2, "w")
except IOError:
    print("Error reading file! Program ends here")
    endofprogram = True           
    if (endofprogram == False):
        dangerous = 0
        largesafe = 0
        animals = 0
        browndanger = 0
        saferedhard = 0
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            if (line != " ") and (line[0] != "#"):
                lineparts = line.split()
                if lineparts:
                    animals = animals +1                    
                    if lineparts[3] == "dangerous":
                        dangerous = dangerous + 1
                    elif lineparts[1] == "large" and lineparts[3] == "safe":
                        largesafe = largesafe + 1
                    elif lineparts[0] == "brown" and lineparts[3] == "dangerous":
                        browndanger = browndanger + 1
                    elif (lineparts[0] == "red" )and ((lineparts[3] == safe) or (lineparts[2])):
                        saferedhard == saferedhard + 1


                ofile.write("Animals = \n" + str(animals))
                ofile.write("Dangerous = \n" + str(dangerous))
                ofile.write("Brown and dangerous = \n" + str(browndanger)) 
                ofile.write("Large and safe = \n", + str(largesafe))
                ofile.write("Safe and red color or hard flesh= \n", + str(saferedhard))

            infile.close()
            ofile.close()
```

Comment: You don't actually have any code that outputs a file.

Comment: where did you get that code from? :)

Comment: Isn't that the point of the  ofile = open(filename2, "w") and ofile.write("Animals = \n" + str(animals))
                ofile.write("Dangerous = \n" + str(dangerous))
                ofile.write("Brown and dangerous = \n" + str(browndanger)) 
                ofile.write("Large and safe = \n", + str(largesafe))
                ofile.write("Safe and red color or hard flesh= \n", + str(saferedhard))

or do I just not understand python I/O at all.

Comment: @alko I wrote it myself. Why do you ask?

Comment: Posted code should be short, self-contained and compilable (http://sscce.org/). This example is anything but short. Please rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks Misha. I am fairly new to python so I tend to take things down to their very basic forms so my code tends to end up long. I will use the sscce guide to try to trim it.

Comment: @user2767528 Keep in mind that the sscce guidelines apply to **examples** that you are sharing with other people. It is not a set of guidelines for how you should actually write your code.

Answer (score 1):

Dedent the `if` statement following the try block:

```
import os.path
endofprogram = False

try:
    ...
except IOError:
    print("Error reading file! Program ends here")
    endofprogram = True           
if (endofprogram == False): # This logic is independent of whether an error occurs.
    dangerous = 0
    ...
```

Comment: The code still does not work. I end up getting an indexerror after the change on this line if (line != " ") and (line[0] != "#"): but I am sure there is no index error there.

Comment: @user2767528 This is an entirely unrelated issue from your original question, but the problem is that accessing the first character of an empty line causes an IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os.path #Needs to be just os, not just that.
```